# Maximum call stack exceeded - prior to making any calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am familiar with the `maximum call stack exceeded` error, however when I've seen it before I've always had a large stack trace where it is obvious what caused it.

In this case my stack trace is 1 deep, as in I make the call and it fails before the call goes through.

One thing I did notice, the `Function.length` property of the function being called doesnt state a numeric value - it states the `Maximum call stack exceeded` error.

The function in question has zero arguments, but does return a promise that takes a large function:

```
var a100413 = function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //about 15000 lines
  })
}
```

the promise in turn has many other promises and function definitions.

EDIT:
Looks like  this happens when you nest promises 131 layers deep, however - it does occur before the first call to `test()` - perhaps there is a precompiler that tries to execute the code? I'm using chrome if that makes any difference

I recognise that 131 layers of nesting is a bad program structure, but in this case it is difficult to avoid, I was under the impression that with async code I didnt need to worry about stack size

```
function test(){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){   
   //repeated another 127 times
   //...
    function test(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){       
            function test(){
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){       
                    function test(){
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){   
                            console.log("test")
                            resolve();
                        })
                    }
                    return Promise.resolve(true).then(test).then(resolve)
                })
            }
            return Promise.resolve(true).then(test).then(resolve)
        })
    }   
    //.....
    return Promise.resolve(true).then(test).then(resolve)
})
}   
test().then(function(){console.log("done")})
```

Comment: The call to the 15,000 lines (!!) will be synchronous with the above\*, so we really can't help you without them (and of course, quoting them would be unuseful). You'll have to pare it down to an [mcve] (during which you'll probably figure it out). (\* Remember - promise *resolution* is async, not promise setup.)

Comment: Does it only happen when the function is really long?

Comment: Please confirm that the "Async" checkbox is checked in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - its not even getting to return the Promise, thats what's strange. It fails before the call to `a100413`. If I type `a100413()` with a breakpoint set - the breakpoint doesn't get triggered - yes, the 15k lines is crazy, its being generated automatically though, so not much I can do. It was a lot worse, closer to 130k lines.

Comment: @BenAston - yes it is, but my understanding is that async callbacks don't increase the actual stack depth, so there should be no stack overflow there

Comment: @ZackNewsham this is a junk question. You've shown a Promise constructor with a completely omitted body. You could say `// about 1 line of code` and we'd still have no way of helping you if we didn't know what was happening in that code. Instead, you have 15,000 lines of code inside your Promise, lol. You have much bigger problems than "my cod [that I didn't show here] has a stack overflow."

Comment: @naomik the content of the promise isn't the problem. The level of nesting is. I have no control over the 15k lines. I'm well aware it's ridiculous. It's the output of a generated script. I'm mostly interested in why it's happening before the function is called. Stack overflow usually is caused by too many calls. Not to many nested definitions. It's not something I've come across.

Answer (score -1):

The executor function passed to the `Promise` constructor function is executed immediately.

Therefore the call-stack is likely being blown by the executor function.

Pare-down the 15k lines 50% (binary search) at a time until the error is not being thrown to locate the issue.

Comment: I dont think this is the case, the call to `a100413 ` doesnt go through, it doesnt even get to the line to create the Promise